# What is the determinant of Bernoulli matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $n$ be an even integer, what is the determinant of

$$D_{n+1}=\begin{vmatrix}
  1&1&\cdots&1&1\\
  2&2^2&\cdots&2^n&2^{n+1}\\
  \vdots&\vdots&\cdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
  n&n^2&\cdots&n^n&n^{n+1}\\
  \frac{n}{2}&\frac{n^2}{3}&\cdots&\frac{n^n}{n+1}&\frac{n^{n+1}}{n+2}\\
\end{vmatrix}.$$
At first, we can compute that $D_3=D_5=0$, so there is a high possibility that $D_{n+1}=0$. The last row of the determinant remind me the Bernoulli identity
\begin{align*}
    1+2+\cdots+n &= \frac{n^2}{2}+\frac{n}{2} \\
    1^2+2^2+\cdots+n^2 &=\frac{n^3}{3}+\frac{n^2}{2}+\frac{n}{6}\\
    1^3+2^3+\cdots+n^3 &=\frac{n^4}{4}+\frac{n^3}{2}+\frac{n^2}{4}\\
    1^4+2^4+\cdots+n^4 &=\frac{n^5}{5}+\frac{n^4}{2}+\frac{n^3}{3}-\frac{n}{30}\\
    1^k+2^k+\cdots+n^k &=\frac{n^{k+1}}{k+1}+\frac{n^k}{2}+{\color{red}\frac1{k+1}\left( \binom{k+1} 2B_2n^{k-1}+\cdots+\binom{k+1}kB_kn\right)}
  \end{align*}
Then we change the determinant to
$$D_{n+1}=\frac{-1}{n}\begin{vmatrix}
  1&1&\cdots&1&1\\
  2&2^2&\cdots&2^n&2^{n+1}\\
  \vdots&\vdots&\cdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
  n&n^2&\cdots&n^n&n^{n+1}\\
  -\frac{n^2}{2}&-\frac{n^3}{3}&\cdots&-\frac{n^{n+1}}{n+1}&\frac{-n^{n+2}}{n+2}\\
\end{vmatrix}.$$
Then add the first $n$ line to the last line to obtain
$$D_{n+1}=\frac{-1}{n}\begin{vmatrix}
  1&1&\cdots&1&1\\
  2&2^2&\cdots&2^n&2^{n+1}\\
  \vdots&\vdots&\cdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
  n&n^2&\cdots&n^n&n^{n+1}\\
  \frac{n}{2}&\frac{n^2}{2}+\frac{n}{6}&\cdots&\frac{n^{n}}{2}+\frac{n^n}{12}{\color{red}+\cdots}&\frac{n^{n+1}}{2}
  +\frac{n^{n+1}}{12}+\frac{n^n}{12}{\color{red}+\cdots}\\
\end{vmatrix}.$$
Now Subtract $n$ times the first column from the second column,
$n^2$ times the first column from the third column, and
$n^3$ times the first column from the fourth column and so on
we obtain
$$D_{n+1}=\frac{-1}{n}\begin{vmatrix}
  1&\ast&\cdots&\ast&\ast\\
  2&\ast&\cdots&\ast&\ast\\
  \vdots&\vdots&\cdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
  n&0&\cdots&0&0\\
  \frac{n}{2}&\frac{n}{6}&\cdots&\frac{n^n}{12}{\color{red}+\cdots}&\frac{n^{n+1}}{12}+\frac{n^n}{12}{\color{red}+\cdots}\\
\end{vmatrix}.$$
Then add the $-1/2$ times of the penultimate column to the last column we have that
$$D_{n+1}=\frac{-1}{n}\begin{vmatrix}
  1&\ast&\cdots&\ast&\ast\\
  2&\ast&\cdots&\ast&\ast\\
  \vdots&\vdots&\cdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
  n&0&\cdots&0&0\\
  0&\frac{n}{6}&\cdots&\frac{n^n}{12}{\color{red}+\cdots}&\frac{n^{n+1}}{12}+\frac{n^n}{12}{\color{red}+\cdots}\\
\end{vmatrix}.$$
Then use the $n/6$ in the last line to eliminate all other elements in the last line we have that
$$D_{n+1}=\frac{-1}{n}\begin{vmatrix}
  1&\ast&\cdots&\ast&\ast\\
  2&\ast&\cdots&\ast&\ast\\
  \vdots&\vdots&\cdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
  n&0&\cdots&0&0\\
  0&\frac{n}{6}&\cdots&0&0\\
\end{vmatrix}.$$
At this point, I don't know how to proceed. Can anyone help me？

Comment: Did you try elementary row operations?

Answer (score 1):

Formulated in Mathematica, for the first rows

```
     M[n_] := Outer[(#1^#2 &), Range[n], Range[n + 1]]
```

and the last row appended

```
     MM[n_] := Append[M[n],  n^Range[1, n + 1]/ Range[2, n + 2] ]
```

one finds a linear combination of the first rows equating the last row

```
Solve[{a, b, c, d, e, f} . M[6] == MM[6][[-1]], {a, b, c, d, e, f}][[1]] 

  {{a -> 216/105, b -> 27/840, c -> 272/105, d -> 27/840, e -> 216/105,
  f -> 41/840}}
```

or commmon denominator removed

```
  {a -> 216, b -> 27, c -> 272, d -> 27, e -> 216, f -> 41}
```

This indicates, that trivial line by line reductions will not work the easy way.

Have a look at the `[Vandermonde matrix][1]`

Comment: Why not compute the determinant for the first few values of $n$?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Thank you for your answer. I have been busy these days and haven't logged in to mathstack exchange, so I replied late. There is a solution to this problem, which is to convert a constant into a variable and then take the derivative. I will write it out later

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$f(x)=\begin{vmatrix}
  1&1&\cdots&1&1\\
  2&2^2&\cdots&2^n&2^{n+1}\\
  \vdots&\vdots&\cdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
  n&n^2&\cdots&n^n&n^{n+1}\\
  \frac{x}{2}&\frac{x^2}{3}&\cdots&\frac{x^n}{n+1}&\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+2}\\
\end{vmatrix},$$
then $D_{n+1}=f(n)$ and we have that
\begin{eqnarray*}
% \nonumber to remove numbering (before each equation)
  (xf(x))'&=&\begin{vmatrix}
  1&1&\cdots&1&1\\
  2&2^2&\cdots&2^n&2^{n+1}\\
  \vdots&\vdots&\cdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
  n&n^2&\cdots&n^n&n^{n+1}\\
  x&x^2&\cdots&x^n&x^{n+1}\\
\end{vmatrix}=n!x\begin{vmatrix}
  1&1&\cdots&1&1\\
  1&2&\cdots&2^{n-1}&2^{n}\\
  \vdots&\vdots&\cdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
  1&n&\cdots&n^{n-1}&n^{n}\\
  1&x&\cdots&x^{n-1}&x^{n}\\
\end{vmatrix} \\
   &=&n!x(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-n)\prod_{1\leq i<j\leq n}(j-i)=\left(\prod_{k=1}^nk!\right)x(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-n).
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence
$$xf(x)=\int_0^x(tf(t))'\,dt=\left(\prod_{k=1}^nk!\right)\int_0^xt(t-1)(t-2)\cdots(t-n)\,dt.$$
Since $n$ is even, we have that
$$nf(n)=\left(\prod_{k=1}^nk!\right)\int_0^nt(t-1)(t-2)\cdots(t-n)\,dt=0.$$
Here we use the fact that function
$$g(x):=x(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-n)$$
is an odd function with respect to
$x=n/2$. For example, $f(x)=x^3$ or $\sin x$ is an odd function with respect to $x=0$ in the usuall sense.